# How to get only the unique results without having to sort data?

Tags: text-processing, uniq

```
$ cat data.txt 
aaaaaa
aaaaaa
cccccc
aaaaaa
aaaaaa
bbbbbb
$ cat data.txt | uniq
aaaaaa
cccccc
aaaaaa
bbbbbb
$ cat data.txt | sort | uniq
aaaaaa
bbbbbb
cccccc
$
```

The result that I need is to **display all the lines from the original file removing all the duplicates (not just the consecutive ones), while maintaining the original order of statements in the file**.

Here, in this example, the result that I actually was looking for was

```
aaaaaa
cccccc
bbbbbb
```

How can I perform this generalized `uniq` operation in general?

Answer (score 75, accepted):

```
perl -ne 'print unless $seen{$_}++' data.txt
```

Or, if you must have a [useless use of `cat`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_%28Unix%29#Useless_use_of_cat):

```
cat data.txt | perl -ne 'print unless $seen{$_}++'
```

Here's an `awk` translation, for systems that lack Perl:

```
awk '!seen[$0]++' data.txt
cat data.txt | awk '!seen[$0]++'
```

Comment: A slightly shorter awk script is `{ if (!seen[$0]++) print }`

Comment: general info: I time tested both perl and awk... awk was faster by 25+%)... 450000 unique lines (doubled up) to make 900000 lines (4 bytes per line)

Comment: @fred, unless your file is truly huge, either version takes longer to type in than it does to run.

Comment: The awk version can be made even shorter by leaving out the `if`, `print`, parentheses, and braces: `awk '!seen[$0]++'`

Comment: What is `seen`? I've searched the [User's Guide](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html) and can't find anything.

Comment: @Legate, it's the name of [an array](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Arrays) in which we're recording every line we've seen.  You could change it to `'!LarryWall[$0]++'` for all awk cares, but "seen" helps people understand the program better.

Comment: @cjm: I think I get it - mostly: It's an ordinary user-defined array and every input line is added as an index, though without a corresponding value. But what does `++` do?

Comment: I merged several lists of special characters from different websites into a single plain text file (https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/39189022/SpecialCharacters.txt) and tried to get rid of duplicates to make a proper list, using different commands I could find, including this one. But the result was always unsatisfactory, including many duplicates and so on (https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/39189022/SpecialCharacters-SortUnique.txt) This casts a doubt in my mind on the reliability of these commands which I use from time to time on some important data :\) I wonder why this is so???

Comment: @Sadi, that really should have been asked as a question, not a comment.  But some of the lines in that file end in a space, and some don't.  These commands consider the entire line significant, including the whitespace at the end.

Comment: Ooops, I didn't notice the spaces at the end of some lines; thank you! I just didn't want to be warned of a duplicate question.

Comment: @Sadi, if you link to the original question/answer and then explain why it doesn't solve your problem, it won't be closed as a duplicate.  (It might get closed for some other reason, but not that.)

Comment: The `awk` trick is also well explained [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11532197/2192488).

Comment: awk one is VERY fast at time()!

Answer (score 20):

[john](http://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=john&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all) has a tool called `unique`:

```
usr@srv % cat data.txt | unique out
usr@srv % cat out
aaaaaa
cccccc
bbbbbb
```

To achieve the same without additional tools in a single commandline is a bit more complex:

```
usr@srv % cat data.txt | nl | sort -k 2 | uniq -f 1 | sort -n | sed 's/\s*[0-9]\+\s\+//'
aaaaaa
cccccc
bbbbbb
```

`nl` prints line numbers in front of the lines, so if we `sort`/`uniq` behind them, we can restore the original order of the lines. `sed` just deletes the line numbers afterwards ;)

Comment: is there any combination of common linux commands that could do the same?

Comment: @Totor - see _menkus_' [reply](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11939/how-to-get-only-the-unique-results-without-having-to-sort-data#comment127925_84838) to a similar comment .  @binfalse - your second solution does not work (maybe it works with this trivial sample but it doesn't work with some real life input). Please fix that, e.g. this should always work: `nl -ba -nrz data.txt | sort -k2 -u | sort | cut -f2`

Answer (score 12):

I prefer to use this:

```
cat -n data.txt | sort --key=2.1 -b -u | sort -n | cut -c8-
```

`cat -n` adds line numbers,

`sort --key=2.1 -b -u` sorts on the second field (after the added line numbers), ignoring leading blanks, keeping unique lines

`sort -n` sorts in strict numeric order

`cut -c8-` keep all characters from column 8 to EOL (i.e., omit the line numbers we included)

Comment: >How to get only the unique results without having to sort data?

>without having to sort data

Comment: 'without having to sort the data' only appears in the title. The actual need is to: "display all the lines from the original file removing all the duplicates (not just the consecutive ones), while maintaining the original order of statements in the file."

Comment: The same thing, but using tabs as the delimiter for the line numbers: `awk -v OFS='\t' '{ print NR, $0 }' data.txt | sort -u -b -k 2 | sort -n | cut -f 2-`

Answer (score 3):

Perl has a module that you can use that includes a function called `uniq`. So if you ave your data loaded in an array in Perl you simply call the function like this to make it unique, yet still maintain the original order.

```
use List::MoreUtils qw(uniq)    
@output = uniq(@output);
```

You can read more about this module here: [List::MoreUtils](http://search.cpan.org/dist/List-MoreUtils/lib/List/MoreUtils.pm)

Comment: Can this handle huge files, e.g. 500 GB?

Answer (score 0):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```
~$ raku -e '.put for lines.unique;'  file
```

*OR (more [`awk`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1444406/how-to-delete-duplicate-lines-in-a-file-without-sorting-it-in-unix)-like syntax):*

```
~$ raku -ne 'state %h; .put unless %h{$_}++ ;'  file
```

Sample Input:

```
aaaaaa
aaaaaa
cccccc
aaaaaa
aaaaaa
bbbbbb
```

Sample Output:

```
aaaaaa
cccccc
bbbbbb
```

https://docs.raku.org
https://raku.org