# How to remove duplicate lines in a large multi-GB textfile?

Tags: linux, text-processing, uniq

My question is similar to [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11939/how-to-get-only-the-unique-results-without-having-to-sort-data) but with a couple of different constraints:

- I have a large `\n` delimited wordlist -- one word per line. Size of
  files range from 2GB to as large as 10GB.
- I need to remove any duplicate lines.
- The process may sort the list during the course of removing the duplicates but not required.
- There is enough space on the partition to hold the new unique wordlist outputted.

I have tried both of these methods but they both fail with out of memory errors.

```
sort -u wordlist.lst > wordlist_unique.lst
```

```
awk '!seen[$0]++' wordlist.lst > wordlist_unique.lst
awk: (FILENAME=wordlist.lst FNR=43601815) fatal: assoc_lookup: bucket-ahname_str: can't allocate 10 bytes of memory (Cannot allocate memory)
```

What other approaches can I try?

Comment: Have a look at a solution using awk http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/30178/56820

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try using sort with the `-o`/`--output=FILE` option instead of redirecting the output.  You might also try setting the `buffer-size` with the `-S`/`--buffer-size=SIZE`.  Also, try `-s`/`--stable`.  And read the man page, it offers all of the info I gave.

The full command you can use that might work for what you're doing:

```
sort -us -o wordlist_unique.lst wordlist.lst
```

You might also want to read the following URL:

http://www.gnu.org/s/coreutils/manual/html_node/sort-invocation.html

That more thoroughly explains sort than the man page.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, unfortunately using --output still doesn't fix the out of memory error. Running that still gives me `sort: write failed: /root/tmp/sortVxscLn: No space left on device`. The problem is a bit annoying in that it doesn't fail right away. It seems like you have to wait for the memory to get exhausted before it will error out.

Comment: @Victor T.: That is not an out of memory error, but an out of disk space error. Is /root on a different filesystem to your data? If so, use the -T/--temporary-directory option to `sort` to use a filesystem with more free space.

Comment: @camh thanks that did the trick. Didn't realize you could specify which intermediate buffer to use.