# How to remove duplicate lines inside a text file?

Tags: files, text-processing, large-files

A huge (up to 2 GiB) text file of mine contains about 100 exact duplicates of every line in it (useless in my case, as the file is a CSV-like data table).

What I need is to remove all the repetitions while (preferably, but this can be sacrificed for a significant performance boost) maintaining the original sequence order. In the result each line is to be unique. If there were 100 equal lines (usually the duplicates are spread across the file and won't be neighbours) there is to be only one of the kind left.

I have written a program in Scala (consider it Java if you don't know about Scala) to implement this. But maybe there are faster C-written native tools able to do this faster?

UPDATE: the `awk '!seen[$0]++' filename` solution seemed working just fine for me as long as the files were near 2 GiB or smaller but now as I am to clean-up a 8 GiB file it doesn't work any more. It seems taking infinity on a Mac with 4 GiB RAM and a 64-bit Windows 7 PC with 4 GiB RAM and 6 GiB swap just runs out of memory. And I don't feel enthusiastic about trying it on Linux with 4 GiB RAM given this experience.

Comment: this will destroy your ordering but,have you tried sort -u, I have no idea how or if it can run on such a massive file

Comment: C is often not significantly faster than Java, and if you're running it (in-order) now, there's a fair chance it'll finish before you get an answer here, implement it, and it finishes running; out of order, `sort -u` will probably be faster.

Answer (score 345, accepted):

An `awk` solution seen on #bash (Freenode):

```
awk '!seen[$0]++' filename
```

If you want to edit the file in-place, you can use the following command (provided that you use a GNU awk version that implements this extension):

```
awk -i inplace '!seen[$0]++' filename
```

Comment: Just tried this on a 2G file and it took three minutes on my notebook.  Not bad.  I also tried uniq filename | awk '!seen[$0]++', but it wasn't any faster.

Comment: This is surprisingly faster than a more verbose `awk` version using 2 array lookups (shown as an expanded explanation in Gilles answer) :  *0m36.132s* vs *0m49.958s*.. for 50 million lines.. I thought the bottleneck would be the I/O, but the extra array lookup is... 1 million elements in the array seems to make a rather significant dent...

Comment: But how does that compare to sort -u .... ?

Comment: @HashWizard: this command does not sort, but eliminates every next occurrence of the same line

Comment: Wondering how this command works? -- See here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/159695/how-does-awk-a0-work

Comment: How do you replace the file with this text?

Comment: Will this work if the duplicates are randomly distributed, rather than next to each other?

Comment: @0x499602D2 To replace the file you would pipe it back at the file: `awk'!seen[$0]++' filename > filename`. This is probably a bad idea though, you probably want to do `awk'!seen[$0]++' filename > newfilename` to make sure it works correctly before deleting the old one.

Comment: @MaxWilliams yes, it works is they are randomly distributed.

Comment: In case you wanted to retain the last occurrence of the repeated line:  `tac filename | awk '!seen[$0]++' | tac > newfilename`  - but maybe `awk` could do it without `tac`?

Comment: preserve newlines or lines with spaces `awk '/^\s*?$/||!seen[$0]++' `

Comment: What is this charm !?!?!

Comment: Can we also do: ` awk '!seen[$0]++' filename > filename`?

Comment: On macOS: "awk: can't open file !seen[$0]++ source line number 1"

Comment: FYI for others, the in-place option does __NOT__ work on Ubuntu.

Comment: @Raleigh, I think the default version of awk in Ubuntu is mawk, not GNU awk, and the answer expressly talks about GNU awk when reporting the `--in-place` option.

Answer (score 56):

There's a simple (which is not to say obvious) method using standard utilities which doesn't require a large memory except to run `sort`, which in most implementations has specific optimizations for huge files (a good external sort algorithm). An advantage of this method is that it only loops over all the lines inside special-purpose utilities, never inside interpreted languages.

```
<input nl -b a -s : |           # number the lines
sort -t : -k 2 -u |             # sort and uniquify ignoring the line numbers
sort -t : -k 1n |               # sort according to the line numbers
cut -d : -f 2- >output          # remove the line numbers
```

If all lines begin with a non-whitespace character, you can dispense with some of the options:

```
<input nl | sort -k 2 -u | sort -k 1n | cut -f 2- >output
```

For a large amount of duplication, a method that only requires storing a single copy of each line in memory will perform better. With some interpretation overhead, there's a very concise awk script for that (already [posted by enzotib](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/30173/how-to-remove-duplicate-lines-inside-a-text-file/30178#30178)):

```
<input awk '!seen[$0]++'
```

Less concisely: `!seen[$0] {print} {seen[$0] += 1}`, i.e. print the current line if it hasn't been seen yet, then increment the `seen` counter for this line (uninitialized variables or array elements have the numerical value 0).

For long lines, you can save memory by keeping only a non-spoofable checksum (e.g. a cryptographic digest) of each line. For example, using SHA-1, you only need 20 bytes plus a constant overhead per line. But computing digests is rather slow; this method will only win if you have a fast CPU (especially one with a hardware accelerator to compute the digests) and not a lot of memory relative to the size of the file and sufficiently long lines. No basic utility lets you compute a checksum for each line; you'd have to bear the interpretation overhead of Perl/Python/Ruby/… or write a dedicated compiled program.

```
<input perl -MDigest::MD5 -ne '$seen{Digest::MD5::md5($_)}++ or print' >output
```

Comment: @Gilles Based on your explanation of `awk '!seen[$0]++'`, does it mean that if awk sees 2 duplicate lines, it will keep the always first one and ignore all subsequent ones? (Or it will keep the last one?)

Comment: @user779159 It keeps the first one: each input line is either printed immediately (first occurrence) or not at all (repeat occurrence).

Comment: But how does that compare to sort -u ...?

Comment: @HashWizard A plain `sort -u` changes the order. My answer shows solutions that preserve the order (the order of first occurrences, to be precise).

Comment: @Gilles would you say that it is faster than sort -u for large files (10G) with 50% duplicates ?

Comment: @HashWizard Do you care about order or not? If you don't I'd expect `sort -u` to be faster, because the awk method would use a lot of memory and swap, and the pipes around sort are obviously slower than sort alone.

Answer (score 56):

```
sort -u big-csv-file.csv > duplicates-removed.csv
```

Note that the output file will be sorted.

Comment: Not as fast as the `awk` command in other answers, but conceptually simple!

Comment: @Johann I am doing this pretty often on files with hundreds of thousands (even million) of short newline terminated strings. I get the results pretty quick for the experiments I am doing. It can be more important if used in scripts which are run again and again, savings in time can be considerable.

Comment: Use `sort -u` to remove duplicates during the sort, rather than after.  (And saves memory bandwidth) piping it to another program).  This is only better than the `awk` version if you want your output sorted, too.  (The OP on this question wants his original ordering *preserved*, so this is a good answer for a slightly different use-case.)

Comment: Took about a minute, for me, for a 5.5 million line file (1.8 GB in total).  Brilliant.

Answer (score 23):

Assuming you can afford to keep as much as the de-duplicated file in memory (if your data is indeed duplicated by a factor of 100, that should be about 20MiB + overhead), you can do this very easily with Perl.

```
$ perl -ne 'print unless $dup{$_}++;' input_file > output_file
```

This preserves the order too.

You could extract the number of occurrences of each line from the `%dup` hash if you so wished, as an added free bonus.

If you prefer `awk`, this should do it too (same logic as the perl version, same ordering, same data gathered in the `dup` variable):

```
$ awk '{if (++dup[$0] == 1) print $0;}' input_file > output_file
```

Comment: This is too good @Mat, I was about to slurp the file, lol ;-).

Comment: Now waiting for @ManAtWork for his sed and awk magic weavery too :-)

Comment: awesome again for the awk tip :-)

Comment: Is it possible to change the perl script to only remove duplicate adjacent lines?

Comment: @dumbledad: `uniq` does that all by itself

Comment: for me awk is working but uniq is not. any idea?
this is the output of uniq -c:
 1 hello
   1 heloo
   1 hello
   1 this is me
   1 hello
   1 this is me
   1 hello
   2 i am awesome
   1 i am a board
   1 i am

Answer (score 14):

As no other answer provided inplace support, here is one:

```
gawk -i inplace '!a[$0]++' file
```

Comment: Does this preserve the order? By the way, this did not work for me. My version is: `GNU Awk 4.0.2`

Comment: @Leonid yes, it does. It prints the first occurrence of any unique line. The inplace support was first introduced in version 4.1, which was released in 2013.

Comment: This should be the answer. It's actually delete the duplicated string in the existing or current file where the top answer and most of the answers here only printout the uniq / duplicated strings and doing nothing and we have to create another output to store the result.

Comment: How does `gawk` differs from `awk`?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `uniq` http://www.computerhope.com/unix/uuniq.htm

`uniq` reports or filters out repeated lines in a file.

Comment: When giving an answer it is preferable to give [some explanation as to WHY your answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) is the one.  So, how does this answer differ from several of the previous answers?

Comment: From the uniq man page:Note: 
```'uniq'  does  not  detect repeated lines unless they are adjacent.```

So you have to first sort it and loose the order of the non duplicate lines.

Answer (score 3):

**SOLUTION WITHOUT MAINTAINING THE ORIGINAL SEQUENCE ORDER**

I did it with the following code piece.

```
sort duplicates.txt | uniq > noDuplicates.txt
```

The `sort` command sorts the lines alphabetically, and the `uniq` command removes the duplicates.

**NOTE:** *Why we sorted the lines first is that `uniq` does not detect duplicate lines unless they are adjacent.*

Comment: The question asks for a method (preferably) which maintains the input order; could you [edit] your answer to address that? Note that there are existing answers using `sort` which maintain input order, and [one answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/190055/86440) using `sort` without maintaining input order but in a more efficient manner than piping to `uniq`.

Comment: @StephenKitt Edited. I inspected other answers, but couldn't find anything only with basic commands. Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: I gave you [a link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/190055/86440) to an answer with only basic commands, in fact only one command, `sort -u` (which is part of [POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sort.html)) ;-).

Comment: @StephenKitt I saw that answer. Mine is also a way to handle the problem. What do you want me to do more? Should I delete the answer?

Comment: No, don’t delete your answer; I just wanted to make sure you were aware of the other answer, given that you said you “couldn't find anything only with basic commands”.

Comment: @StephenKitt Actually, you are right. It is more basic than mine. Thanks. Have a good day.

Answer (score 2):

**Python One liners :**

```
python -c "import sys; lines = sys.stdin.readlines(); print ''.join(sorted(set(lines)))" < InputFile
```

Comment: this causes the entire file to be slurped into memory and may not be a good fit for the OP's problem. Also not guaranteed to retain order

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I've been just learning python.. just tried this for learning purpose.. :)

Comment: [Here's](http://paste.ubuntu.com/6115665/) a Python 2.7 version that is not a one-liner but (succinctly) returns unique lines preserving order without either loading the entire file into memory or creating a single gigantic string to feed to print

Comment: Thanks @1_CR I have something learn today :) `OrderedDict`

Answer (score 0):

None of the answers here worked for me on my Mac so I wrote a simple python script that works for me. I am ignoring leading/trailing whitespace and also don't care about memory consumption.

```
import sys

inputfile = sys.argv[1]
outputfile = sys.argv[2]

with open(inputfile) as f:
    content = f.readlines()

content = [x.strip() for x in content]

my_list = list(set(content))

with open(outputfile, 'w') as output:
    for item in my_list:
        output.write("%s\n" % item)
```

Save the above to unique.py and run like this:

```
python unique.py inputfile.txt outputfile.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```perl
~$ raku -ne 'BEGIN my %dup; .put unless %dup{$_}++;'  input_file > output_file
```

OR:

```perl
~$ raku -e '.put for lines.unique;'  input_file > output_file
```

*[ Note: compare first answer here with excellent Perl answer by @Mat ].*

https://docs.raku.org
https://raku.org

Answer (score 0):

Note that `sort` can write its output to any one of the files that it was given as input:

```
LC_ALL=C sort -u -o input input
```

That's fine as `sort` needs to have read all its input before it can start outputting anything (before it can tell which is the line that sorts first which could very well be the last line of the input).

`sort` will (intelligently) use temporary files so as to avoid loading the whole input in memory. You'll need enough space in `$TMPDIR` (or `/tmp` if that variable is not set). Some `sort` implementations can compress the temp files (like with `--compress-program=lzop` with GNU `sort`) which can help if you're short on disk space or have slow disks.

With `LC_ALL=C` sort order is by byte value which should speed things up and also guarantee a total and deterministic order (which you don't always get otherwise especially on GNU systems).

Answer (score -1):

With bash 4, a pure-bash solution that takes advantage of [associative arrays](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Arrays.html) can be used. Here is an example

```
unset llist; declare -A llist;
while read -r line; do
if [[ ${llist[$line]} ]]; then
  continue
else 
  printf '%s\n' "$line"
  llist[$line]="x"
fi
done < file.txt
```

Comment: Don't use `read` loops to process big text files.  bash has to read one-byte-at-a-time to avoid overshooting a newline.  Bash is also not very fast at text processing in general compared to awk.  If you do use this, `read -ra` will avoid eating backslashes in your input.  Also, don't forget to `unset llist` *after* the loop, if you put this in a shell function or use it interactively.

Comment: @PeterCordes, or you could have just referenced [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/169765/21233) :-)