# Remove entire row in a file if first column is repeated

Tags: awk

I have a file containing two columns and 10 million rows. The first column contains many repeated values, but there is a distinct value in column 2. I want to remove the repeated rows and want to keep only one using `awk`. Note: the file is sorted with values in column 1. For example:

```
1.123 -4.0
2.234 -3.5
2.234 -3.1
2.234 -2.0
4.432 0.0
5.123 +0.2
8.654 +0.5
8.654 +0.8
8.654 +0.9
.
.
.
.
```

Expected output

```
1.123 -4.0
2.234 -3.5
4.432 0.0
5.123 +0.2
8.654 +0.5
.
.
.
.
```

Comment: You may find this recent question useful http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/159695/65304

Comment: Simply: `sort -buk1,1`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A few ways:

1. awk

   ```
   awk '!a[$1]++' file
   ```

   This is a very condensed way of writing this:

   ```
   awk '{if(! a[$1]){print; a[$1]++}}' file
   ```

   So, if the current first field (`$1`) is not in the `a` array, print the line and add the 1st field to `a`. Next time we see that field, it will be in the array and so will not be printed.
2. Perl

   ```perl
   perl -ane '$k{$F[0]}++ or print' file
   ```

   or

   ```
   perl -ane 'print if !$k{$F[0]}++' file
   ```

   This is basically the same as the `awk` one. The `-n` causes perl to read the input file line by line and apply the script provided by `-e` to each line. The `-a` will automatically split each line on whitespace and save the resulting fields in the `@F` array. Finally, the first field is added to the `%k` hash and if it is not already there, the line is printed. The same thing could be written as

   ```perl
   perl -e 'while(<>){
               @F=split(/\s+/); 
               print unless defined($k{$F[0]}); 
               $k{$F[0]}++;
            }' file
   ```
3. Coreutils

   ```
   rev file | uniq -f 1 | rev
   ```

   This method works by first reversing the lines in `file` so that if a line is 12 345 it'll now be 543 21. We then use `uniq -f 1` to ignore the first field, that is to say, the column that 543 is in. There are fields within `file`. Using `uniq` here has the effect of filtering out any duplicate lines, keeping only 1 of each. Lastly we put the lines back into their original order with another reverse.
4. GNU sort (as [suggested](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/160009/remove-entire-row-in-a-file-if-first-column-is-repeated/160015#comment262290_160009) by @StéphaneChazelas)

   ```
   sort -buk1,1
   ```

   The `-b` flag ignores leading whitespace and the `-u` means print only unique fields. The clever bit is the `-k1,1`. The `-k` flag sets the field to sort on. It takes the general format of `-k POS1[,POS2]` which means only look at fields `POS1` through POS2 when sorting. So, `-k1,1` means only look at the 1st field. 
   Depending on your data, you might want to also add one of these options:

   ```
    -g, --general-numeric-sort
         compare according to general numerical value
    -n, --numeric-sort
         compare according to string numerical value
   ```

Comment: Hmm so that's what `rev` is used for... Thanks.

Comment: I try the awk solution abovve and getting the message  a[: Event not found.

Comment: also after this message when I press up key then the command is changed to awk '$1]++' filename

Comment: @Nilesh did you copy the _exact_ command or did you use double quotes (`"`) instead of single quotes (`'`)?

Comment: I use exactly same command with single quotes.

Comment: @Nilesh what OS, what shell and what `awk` are you using? This works exactly as expected (and in fact is [a classic](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/159695/22222) awk one liner) on Linux/bash/GNU awk.

Comment: @terdon second command is working fine (awk '{if(! a[$1]){print; a[$1]++}}' filename). while first one is not (awk '!a[$1]++' filename). I am on SunOS (uname gave me this). how to know about which shell?

Comment: @Nilesh try `echo $SHELL` or, to be certain, `ps -p $$ | tail -n 1 | awk '{print $NF}'`. Also give the `awk` version. In future, please _always_ mention your OS, there are major differences between the GNU tools and their various UNIX equivalents.

Comment: @Nilesh OK, I just tested and I will guess that you're using `csh`. If so, you need to escape the `!` so use this one: `awk '\!a[$1]++' file`

Comment: Great answer. Perhaps `-n` needs to be added to `sort` invocation to force numeric sorting. Also, would `sort -bukn1,1` be able to take advantage of pre-sorted input? If not , split the input file into chunks using `split` and then pass to `sort -m` I guess

Comment: @1_CR good point, thanks. I added the descriptions of the two relevant options. I don't know the details but some quick testing suggests that `sort -u` is significantly faster on presorted data, yes.

Answer (score 5):

If the first column is always 5 characters long, you can simply use `uniq`:

```
uniq -w 5 file
```

If not, use `awk`:

```
awk '$1!=a{print $0; a=$1}' file
```

The first one would definitely be faster with a huge file.