# Obtaining unique lines with matching strings

Tags: shell-script, awk, grep, filter

I have a JSON like text file of records with duplicate ids that look like:

```
{"ID":"93" , "ST":[42,77,51]}
{"ID":"21" , "ST":[43,4]}
{"ID":"94" , "ST":[65,11,4]}
{"ID":"93" , "ST":[42,77,51,29,63]}
{"ID":"73" , "ST":[21,20]}
{"ID":"94" , "ST":[65,11,4]}
{"ID":"77" , "ST":[87]}
```

I am trying to filter the duplicates and always keep the first occurrence of such a match. The field ST could be the same but also different for the records with the same id.

The output would look like:

```
{"ID":"93" , "ST":[42,77,51]}
{"ID":"21" , "ST":[43,4]}
{"ID":"94" , "ST":[65,11,4]}
{"ID":"73" , "ST":[21,20]}
{"ID":"77" , "ST":[87]}
```

A similar question has already been asked [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/160009/remove-entire-row-in-a-file-if-first-column-is-repeated), but for this case the data file being edited was a comma separated file. Here we are dealing with a JSON data and the goal will be to find the lines that have the same id values(may be a regex match) and keep the latest one. Anyone has an idea how to tackle that with awk, sed or pure command line tools?

Comment: I just edited the question that the lines here are not CSV formatted  that's why Stephen's answer didn't work.

Comment: Do you want to keep the first occurrence, or the last one? You ask for both in your latest edit ("keep the first occurrence of such a match", then "keep the latest one").

Answer (score 2):

You can use the usual `awk` de-duplicating technique, on the first field only (fields are separated by spaces):

```
awk '!count[$1]++'
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That doesn't work for the above format.

Comment: @HarryJason I tried it with your example before posting and it worked for me... Note the `$2` rather than `$1` in the linked answer.

Comment: exactly that's working for the example provided that the fields are space separated. But that might not always be the case. Can we consider a more general option that takes the regex into account? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What regex? Could you [edit] your question to explain exactly what you're looking for? If the example you give doesn't correspond to what you're trying to do it's hard to show you something that works...