# How to remove all matching pattern except the top one in sed?

Tags: linux, bash, sed, scripting

**file.txt**

```
1.1.1.1 abc 
1.1.1.1 ccc
1.2.2.2 ddd
1.2.2.2 qqq
1.2.2.2 zzz
```

**Expected result:**

```
1.1.1.1 abc
1.2.2.2 ddd
```

**I tried:**

```
sed -i '/1.1.1.1/d' file.txt 

sed -i '/2.2.2.2/d' file.txt
```

But however it remove all instead of leaving 1 result. How to delete all matching pattern but left 1?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sort` with the `--unique` option to achieve what you want:

```
$ sort --unique --key=1,1 file.txt
1.1.1.1 abc
1.2.2.2 ddd
```

or in short

```
sort -uk1,1 file.txt
```

The `--unique` option suppresses lines with equal fields that were already processed and 
`--key=1,1` defines the first field as sort key (*start* and *end position*).

Comment: Thank you! Im looking for this for ages!

Comment: Is there anyway in sed?

Comment: This might be possible with `sed`, but it I guess it would be quite complicated. Better use `awk` or a another method from linked [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/160015).

Comment: Thank you... Ill check it out!