# delete a line if same line exists in the previous line

Tags: shell-script, text-processing

I want to remove lines which exist already in the previous line from the command line in UNIX. I have the following data in a file.

```
 <xref id="gi_525506931_ref_NP_001266519.1__brain_aromatase"/>
                    <entry ac="IPR002401" desc="Cytochrome P450, E-class, group I" name="Cyt_P450_E_grp-I" type="FAMILY">
                    <entry ac="IPR001128" desc="Cytochrome P450" name="Cyt_P450" type="FAMILY">
                    <entry ac="IPR001128" desc="Cytochrome P450" name="Cyt_P450" type="FAMILY">
                    <entry ac="IPR001128" desc="Cytochrome P450" name="Cyt_P450" type="FAMILY">
```

So, it should look like this:

```
 <xref id="gi_525506931_ref_NP_001266519.1__brain_aromatase"/>
                    <entry ac="IPR002401" desc="Cytochrome P450, E-class, group I" name="Cyt_P450_E_grp-I" type="FAMILY">
                    <entry ac="IPR001128" desc="Cytochrome P450" name="Cyt_P450" type="FAMILY">
```

Comment: Welcome to U&L. We are (often) a pretty forgiving bunch, if you make mistakes we'll tell you or correct them. You can review the changes that I made to your post, just click on the link above my (or any follow up editor's) avatar.

Comment: Hi Anthon, I am not able to accept two answers although  cuonglm's answer also gave me required result. Also, I am not able to upvote the answers.

Comment: Upvoting comes with 15 reputations, wait for it ..., there you go, should have it

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you can guarantee that the identical lines will be consecutive, you can use

```
uniq your_file
```

and [cuonglm's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/166036/26909) will work even if they're not.

Comment: Yes. Thats what I wanted.

Comment: A line is normally consecutive with the previous line (as in the title of the question) ;-)

Comment: @Anthon You're right. But, hey, completeness never hurts :) ([Incompleteness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kurt_G%C3%B6del), on the other hand,...)

Answer (score 4):

With `awk`:

```
awk '!a[$0]++' file
```

An explanation for this idiom you can read [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/159734/38906).

Comment: This also removes doubles that are the same with entries that are not the previous line, the title states "same as the previous line"

Comment: ...cool! Maybe adding a bit of explanation? ;-)

Comment: I second that emotion, @Rmano. Currently indistinguishable from magic :p

Comment: @Rmano and Svish: I add link to explanation.