# read phone numbers from file and store them in other file uniquely

Tags: shell-script

I have input text file e.g `myfile.txt` which is contains data like

```
WO_ID 
------------------------------------------------------------------------
moveover_virus_8493020020_virus.final 
moveover_virus_7483920322_virus.csvwork
```

etc. only phone number is changing I have some 13 work orders like this I need to take only number as a input from this for that I need a script in perl. I need to create that script I am trying grep but I am unable get only numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your input file you can do something like this, using `awk`:

```
awk -F"_" '{print $3}' inputfile | uniq > outputfile
```

or using `grep`,

```
grep -o -E '[0-9]+' inputfile | uniq > outputfile
```

using `sed`,

```
sed 's/[^0-9]*//g;/^\s*$/d' inputfile | uniq
```

Answer (score 1):

no need for `uniq`

```
awk -F"_" 'NF>2 {if ( !a[$3]++) print $3}' inputfile
```

where

- `NF>2` ensure a phone number is present
- `!a[$3]++` will evaluate to `1` first time, `0` other time

Comment: I like your finding unique value approach.

Comment: see http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/159695/how-does-awk-a0-work for further details

Comment: `awk -F_ '$3&&!a[$3]++{print $3}'`

Comment: @123 this is not code golf !

Answer (score 0):

You can utlizise this perl script for your perpose:

```
    #!/bin/perl
    my $str = "moveover_virus_7483920322_virus.csvwork";
    my  $phone = (split /_/, $str)[2];
    print "$phone\n";
```

test the script:

```
    [iahmad@ijaz-cms ~]$ ./perltest 
    7483920322
```

Comment: but I need to take input from a text file which is having 100 work orders like this and I need to delete the repeated values.

Comment: yes u can do that , this is just an example , you can read the file in perl and use a loop through the lines and final output the file

Answer (score 0):

I am a fan of look arounds to do this kind of work. I copied you example data into a text file named "test" and then ran the following

```
$ grep -oP '(?<=s\_).*(?=\_v)' test 
8493020020
7483920322
```

grep -o means return only the match

-P means use Perl regex

?<= means "match anything that comes after s_" (note that the "_" needs to be escaped with the "\")

?= means "match anything that comes before v_" (again note that the "_" needs to be escaped)

So the end result is a match for anything between "s_" (virus_) and "-v" (_virus)

Comment: could you please give me the complete script I am getting errors .I am unable to debug why because I don't know anything about perl

Comment: @rajaputh This is complete. It is a one-line command using grep with the Perl regular expressions. Note that the .* means to match anything between the two regular expressions in the sets of parentheses.