# In awk, how can I make a boolean value that I can toggle it?

Tags: awk

In other programming languages there often has a `bool` or `boolean` type. I can create a boolean type variable and use the `not` operator to toggle it. I can toggle it many times and get a series of true, false, true, false ...

In awk there is no boolean type. Only empty string and the number 0 are considered false. All other values are true. In this case what should I do if I want to do operation A on line 1, 3, 5... and operation B on line 2, 4, 6... The task will very easy if we have a boolean type variable and I can simply `not` it.

Comment: not sure if bool types are there, but you can use [bitwise operations](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Bitwise-Functions.html).. for example: `/condition/{a = xor(a,1)}`

Comment: Does modulo division help? `NR%2  {do A} !(NR%2) {do B}`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

see [How does awk '!a[$0]++' work?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/159695/how-does-awk-a0-work)

basically use `a=!a` this will negate `a` turning 0 to 1 and 1 to 0.

you can test with

```
ls | awk '{a=!a; if ( a ) printf "good %s\n",$0 ; else printf "bad\n";}'
```