# Print line if value in column changes

Tags: awk

I know this should be an easy one by googling but was not successful. Sorry for that.

I would like to print the first line of groups defined the value in the first column. Delimiter is tab.

Input:

```
A 5
A 3
B 2
B 1
B 77
C 4
C 10000
D 99
```

Output:

```
A 5
B 2
C 4
D 99
```

Comment: Googling wasn’t successful ;-). What about trying to figure something out yourself?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The shortest one:

```
awk -F'\t' '!a[$1]++' file
```

The output:

```
A   5
B   2
C   4
D   99
```

---

- `!a[$1]++` - ensures line printing on encountering the first unique value of the 1st column

Comment: no need for `{print $0} ` see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/159695/how-does-awk-a0-work/159697#159697

Comment: @Archemar, indeed, the shortest one )

Comment: Man, this is crazy, and crazy useful

Answer (score 4):

Something like can do the work:

```
awk -F\t 'BEGIN {A=""} {if ($1!=A) { print $0; A=$1}}' input_file
```

When you initialize variable A select initial value which is not in to the list of existing in column 1

Comment: it should be `-F'\t'`, with `-F\t` it outputs all lines for me. https://ibb.co/bZaMNk

Answer (score 2):

Here are two non-awk options:

`sort u foo -k 1,1`

Use `sort` purely for the `-u` (`--unique`) capability. Use only the first character (`-k 1,1`) for comparison.

`rev foo | uniq -f 1 | rev`

Use `uniq`. The `-f` option only allows specifying a start field for comparison, so we use some legerdemain to first reverse (`rev`) the input before `uniq`, and then `rev` that output again.