# Explaining awk code

Tags: awk

Code is being used to remove duplicate entries from histroy.txt file contains history of command line.

```
BEGIN{
      if (data[$0]++ == 0)
         lines[++count] = $0;
     }
END {
     for(i=1; i<count; i++)
         print lines[i];
    }
```

What is `data` in the code and why it is being compared to `0`?

Comment: Are you sure the data & lines code is in the BEGIN block? I'm not sure what $0 would be inside a BEGIN block; they'd make more sense inside the main body.

Comment: oups didn't see the BEGIN ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This intent to remember uniq line in input.

as Jeff Schaller pointed out, `$0` is undefined in `BEGIN` block.

a more correct code should be

```
{
      if (data[$0]++ == 0)
         lines[++count] = $0;
     }
END {
     for(i=1; i<count; i++)
         print lines[i];
    }
```

or even

```
!data[$0]++ { lines[++count] = $0; }
END {
     for(i=1; i<count; i++)
         print lines[i];
    }
```

The first time a line appear `data[$0]` will be equal to 0 and `line[ ]` will receive the line.

After test, `data[$0]` will be incermented (`++` is a post incrementation) and test will evaluate to false for line with same content.

The `END` statement print all the line in order.

see also [How does awk '!a[$0]++' work?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/159695/how-does-awk-a0-work/159697%20How%20!a[$0]++%20work)

Comment: Does that code have any advantage over just `!a[$0]++`?