# awk operator precedence of `!a[$0]++`

Tags: awk

I have an awk expression `!a[$0]++` and I want to know the exact evaluation order. From the document of awk, `++` is at higher precedence than `!`. However, in this example, `++` is in its postfix form (not `!++a[$0]`, which as I understand is basically tells awk, "evaluate other parts first, after that evaluate me". In this case, what's the evaluation order?

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Precedence.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suppose we can agree that `a[$0]` has the highest precedence here(*), so we can just simplify that as `x`.

I'm going to argue that what you read is correct, that `++` has higher precedence than the `!`, so these should be equal:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{ x=123; tmp = !x++;  print tmp, x; }'
0 124
$ awk 'BEGIN{ x=123; tmp = !(x++);  print tmp, x; }'
0 124
```

And indeed they are. `!x++` takes the value of `x`, returns it and increments afterwards. The returned value `123` is negated, yielding `0`. The incremented value can later be found in `x`.

But let's try the other possibility too, that `!` binds tighter:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{ x=123; tmp = (!x)++;  print tmp, x; }'
awk: cmd. line:1: BEGIN{ x=123; tmp = (!x)++;  print tmp, x; }
awk: cmd. line:1:                           ^ syntax error
```

Well, whoops. Now, that can't work, since `!` would first take the value of `x`, then negate it, returning `0`. Now `++` is supposed to increment that, *and store the result back*. But `0` is just a value, not a variable, it cannot be stored to. Hence the error. (Something like `(1+2)++` would give the same error.)

Therefore, `++` has a higher precedence, it just has a hidden side effect that is not apparent from the value it returns.

<sub>(* the subscription operator doesn't appear in the [precedence table](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/awk.html#tag_20_06_13_02) in the standard, as opposed to [operator precedence tables of C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B#Operator_precedence), but if it had lower precedence, the expression really wouldn't work.)</sub>

Comment: I found the following two examples are more specific: `awk 'BEGIN{ x=0; tmp = !++x;  print tmp, x; }'` and `awk 'BEGIN{ x=0; tmp = !x++;  print tmp, x; }'`. Also I found that I can always consider `!x++` as `!x` then `x++` and `!++x` as `++x` then `!x`. They always gives the correct result and is easier to understand.

Comment: @Justalearner, yep, starting with `x=0` makes the difference between pre- and post-increment apparent; and yes, it can help to mentally move them out of the expression. However, if you face something like `a++ + ++a` then that doesn't exactly work... (In C, that's not allowed, in awk it might be well-defined, I don't know. But just hope nobody does that in practice.)

Answer (score 2):

A demo:

```bsh
$ cat file
1 a
2 b
1 c
2 d
3 e
$ awk '!a[$1]++' file
1 a
2 b
3 e
```

`++` happens first. Since it's a post-increment, for the first line, `a[$1]++` increments the value of a[1] but returns zero, and the negation flips that to true, and the first line prints. Same with the 2nd line. For the third line, a[1] already has value 1, the post-increment sets the value to 2 and returns 1, which negated is false.

---

The mawk man page is more clear:

```
   New expressions are composed with the following operators in order of increasing
   precedence.

        assignment          =  +=  -=  *=  /=  %=  ^=
        conditional         ?  :
        logical or          ||
        logical and         &&
        array membership    in
        matching       ~   !~
        relational          <  >   <=  >=  ==  !=
        concatenation       (no explicit operator)
        add ops             +  -
        mul ops             *  /  %
        unary               +  -
        logical not         !
        exponentiation      ^
        inc and dec         ++ -- (both post and pre)
        field               $
```