# remove duplicate lines based on first three column values

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, text-processing, scripting

I am getting a file with content below

[image: 902461360 81636718 32863608 0 employee permenant 902492248 81415224 32775337 0 employee temporary 902495059 81686374 32881482 0 employee permenant 902495059 81686374 32881482 0 employee vendor 902504989 81675052 32877123 0 employee vendor 902532086 81691300 32884527 0 employee vendor 902723910 81690082 32882735 0 employee permenant 902723910 81690082 32882735 0 employee vendor]

The first three values might be repeating in other lines
I want to keep one instance and remove other duplicates

the output should be like below

[image: 902461360 81636718 32863608 0 employee permenant 902492248 81415224 32775337 0 employee temporary 902495059 81686374 32881482 0 employee permenant 902504989 81675052 32877123 0 employee vendor 902532086 81691300 32884527 0 employee vendor 902723910 81690082 32882735 0 employee permenant]

Comment: Please replace the images of the data with the actual data (as text), so that popelp are able to test their solutions. [Don't post images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086)

Comment: Welcome to the site. How do you define "might be repeating"? Do you want to remove a line if _the exact combination of value1, value2 and value2_ has already occured, or if any of value1 _or_ value2 _or_ value3 has already occurred in a previous line?

Answer (score 2):

I would try

```
awk '!a[$1 $2 $3]++ { print ;}' file
```

where

- `!a[$1 $2 $3]++` will evaluate to true first time thoses values are found.

see [How does awk '!a[$0]++' work?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/159695/how-does-awk-a0-work) for more details.

Comment: In the general case, it would be safer to use `a[$1,$2,$3]` (with commas) as that inserts the value of `SUBSEP` between the values that makes up the key instead of just concatenating. A set of `1`, `23`, `4` would otherwise be indistinguishable from the set `12`, `3`, `4`. Also, `{ print; }` is not actually needed.

Comment: thats absolutely solved my issue. Thanks aton

Comment: @sravani Consider [accepting](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) a post that solves your problem.