# How to remove unique strings from a textfile?

Tags: text-processing, sort

Sorry guys I had to edit my example, because I didn't express my query properly.
Let's say I have the .txt file:

```
Happy sad
Happy sad
Happy sad
Sad happy
Happy sad
Happy sad
Mad sad
Mad happy
Mad happy
```

And I want to delete any string that is unique. Leaving the file with:

```
Happy sad
Happy sad
Happy sad
Happy sad
Happy sad
Mad happy
Mad happy
```

I understand that sort is able to get rid of duplicates (`sort file.txt | uniq`), so is there anyway we can do the opposite in bash using a command? Or would I just need to figure out a while loop for it?
BTW `uniq -D file.txt > output.txt` doesn't work.

Comment: What should it give on the output of `printf '%s\n' a b b c a c`? Only `b`, or `a b b c a c` as they're all dupplicated even if not contiguous? Would `b b a a c c` like in @Kusalananda's answer where output is delayed until the second occurrence be acceptable?

Comment: Will `uniq -d` do what you need?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Using `awk`:

```
$ awk 'seen[$0]++; seen[$0] == 2' file
Happy sad
Happy sad
Happy sad
Happy sad
Happy sad
Mad happy
Mad happy
```

This uses the text of each line as the key into the associative array `seen`.  The first `seen[$0]++` will cause a line that has been seen before to be printed since the value associated with the line will be non-zero on the second and subsequent times the line is seen.  The `seen[$0] == 2` causes the line to be printed again if this is the second time the line has been seen (without this, you'll miss one occurrence of each duplicated line).

This is related to  `awk '!seen[$0]++'` which is sometimes used to *remove* duplicates without sorting (see e.g. [How does awk '!a[$0]++' work?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/159695/how-does-awk-a0-work)).

---

To only get one copy of the duplicated lines:

```
awk 'seen[$0]++ == 1' file
```

or,

```
sort file | uniq -d
```

Comment: Note that this can reorder lines, i.e. (space=newline) "a b b b a a" would result in "b b b a a a"

Answer (score 8):

If the duplicates may not be contiguous and you need to preserve the order in the input, you could do it with `awk` and two passes, one to count the number of occurrences and one to print the lines that have been seen to occur more than once in the first pass:

```
awk 'second_pass {if (c[$0] > 1) print; next}
     {c[$0]++}' file.txt second_pass=1 file.txt
```

Comment: Wouldn't the `FNR==NR`-approach work in this case (and be more compact, too)?

Comment: @AdminBee, I don't like the `FNR==NR` code pattern as in the general case, it fails if the first file is empty. Not a problem here, but I prefer advertising the safer flag-based approach. I also find using that `second_pass` flag here makes the code easier to understand.

Comment: Valid point; I didn't consider the case where the first file might be empty. And I agree, the flag can make the code easier to read (and sometimes there is no other portable way, e.g. in "third pass" scenarios) .

Comment: @AdminBee. Related: [Bypass a nawk snippet if the input file is empty](//unix.stackexchange.com/a/237110)

Comment: Also possible to have the first pass store all the input in an array indexed by NR, and traverse that in an END block (instead of reading the file again). Best to check the file size < 200MB or so first.

Answer (score 3):

From `man uniq`:

> **-D**     print all duplicate lines

You can achieve your goal like so:

```
uniq -D file.txt
```

Comment: Note that `-D`  is a non-standard GNU extension, though now supported by a few other implementations including ast-open's and FreeBSD's

Comment: Also note that it only reports duplicate lines that are contiguous. `printf '%s\n' a b a | uniq -D` will print nothing as the two `a` lines are not contiguous. It may very well be what the OP wants though.

Comment: Note that some versions of `uniq` (e.g. on macOS) use a lowercase `-d`

Comment: this appears to work in the OP's example, but if you delete the last `Happy sad` (6th line) in his input, it gives you the wrong answer.  (I am assuming duplicates should be detected even if they are not contiguous, though OP did not actually say that and his example sufficiently illustrate what he wants in that edge case.)

Answer (score 0):

this is probably a Linux-only solution, since it uses `uniq`'s `-u` option.  You could get around that by using `uniq -c` then filtering for `^  *1`  etc. if you're running some other flavour.

```
sort < in | uniq --unique | grep --invert-match --line-regexp --fixed-strings --file - in
```

The first 2 stages will put out

```
Mad sad
Sad happy
```

and the next stage will remove lines that match exactly those lines.  I picked the longer options for clarity; I myself rarely use them  The short form would be `sort < in | uniq -u | grep -v -x -F -f - in`