# Remove duplicate lines from a file that contains a timestamp

Tags: text-processing, awk, duplicate, deduplication

This [question/answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/30173/how-to-remove-duplicate-lines-inside-a-text-file) has some good solutions for deleting identical lines in a file, but won't work in my case since the otherwise duplicate lines have a timestamp.

Is it possible to tell awk to ignore the first 26 characters of a line in determining duplicates?

Example:

```
[Fri Oct 31 20:27:05 2014] The Brown Cow Jumped Over The Moon
[Fri Oct 31 20:27:10 2014] The Brown Cow Jumped Over The Moon
[Fri Oct 31 20:27:13 2014] The Brown Cow Jumped Over The Moon
[Fri Oct 31 20:27:16 2014] The Brown Cow Jumped Over The Moon
[Fri Oct 31 20:27:21 2014] The Brown Cow Jumped Over The Moon
[Fri Oct 31 20:27:22 2014] The Brown Cow Jumped Over The Moon
[Fri Oct 31 20:27:23 2014] The Brown Cow Jumped Over The Moon
[Fri Oct 31 20:27:24 2014] The Brown Cow Jumped Over The Moon
```

Would become

```
[Fri Oct 31 20:27:24 2014] The Brown Cow Jumped Over The Moon
```

(keeping the most recent timestamp)

Comment: Yes. If you were to post some example input and output, then this might amount to a question.

Comment: When asking this type of question, you need to include your input and your desired output. We can't help if we have to guess.

Comment: "yes" or "no" seems to be an acceptable answer, what are you going to do with that knowledge? In case of no, extend awk?

Comment: Wow. 80,000 rep claim this was an unusable question (I would not call it a good one) but not a single close vote?

Comment: @HaukeLaging it seems reasonable to give the OP the chance to react to our comments. They have now done so and the question is greatly improved.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can just use `uniq` with its `-f` option:

```
uniq -f 4 input.txt
```

From `man uniq`:

```
  -f, --skip-fields=N
       avoid comparing the first N fields
```

Actually this will display the first line:

```
[Fri Oct 31 20:27:05 2014] The Brown Cow Jumped Over The Moon
```

If that is a problem you can do:

```
tac input.txt | uniq -f 4
```

or if you don't have `tac` but your `tail` supports `-r`:

```
tail -r input.txt | uniq -f 4
```

Comment: That's wickedly awesome :)

Comment: @Ramesh Some of these tools have some nasty useful options that, when you know them, beat any awk/perl/python stuff you can come up with.

Answer (score 4):

```
awk '!seen[substr($0,27)]++' file
```

Comment: This solution does not cover the timestamp part as that was not part of the question when this answer was written.

Comment: This is exactly why many of us work to close these until the Q's have been fully fleshed out. Otherwise these Q's are wasting your time and the OP's.

Answer (score 3):

Try this one:

```
awk -F ']' '{a[$2]=$1}END{for(i in a){print a[i]"]"i}}'
```

Answer (score 0):

A `perl` solution:

```
perl -F']' -anle '$h{$F[1]} = $_; END{print $h{$_} for keys %h}' file
```

Answer (score 0):

One can use power of `vim`:

```
:g/part of duplicate string/d
```

Very easy. If you have couple more files (such as gzipped *rotated* logs), `vim` will open them without any preliminary uncompression on your side and you can repeat the last command by pressing <kbd>:</kbd> and <kbd>↑</kbd>. Just like repeating last command in terminal.