# Find the top 5 (according to number of packets sent) source IP addresses

Tags: linux, shell, kali-linux, sort, tshark

I am doing an assignment, I'm asked to answer certain questions based on pcap file that I'm given. One of the question is to find the top 5 (according to number of packets sent) source IP addresses.

I have come up with the below command:

```
$ tshark -r assign1.pcap | sort -n -7 | tail -n 5 | awk '{print $3}'
```

where

- `tshark -r` reads the pcap file
- `assign.pcap` is the packet capture file
- `sort -n -7` sorts the file based on column 7 (this column has length of package for each ip address)
- `tail -n 5` print the last 5 records that has the highest length for packet
- `awk  '{print $3}` prints only the third column.

Now here is my problem since I need unique top 5 source ip addresses, so I tried to pipe `uniq` command in the end of script but doesn't help. I also tried to use `sort -u -t, -k3,3` from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1915750/5595994) but this also doesn't print unique ip addresses!

My pcap file column header look like this:

[image]

Comment: can u share the result of tshark?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after getting a hint from [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/30178/298291) answer, I came up with this script:

```
$ tshark -r assign1.pcap | sort -n -r -k7 | awk '!seen[$3]++' | awk '{print $3}' | head -n 5 >> result.txt
```

Explaining each command in the line:

- `tshark -r assign1.pcap` read the pcap file
- `sort -n -r -k7` numeric sort (-n) the file based on (-r) reverse order of (-k7) column 7 [ this column has length of package for each ip address ]
- `awk '!seen[$3]++'` print source ip address (3rd column) that has not been seen before, so this way it prints only unique IPs
- `awk '{print $3}'` only print the 3rd column (source ip address)
- `head -n 5 >> result.txt` since I need the top 5, so I limited my results to only 5 by using the **head** command, also last `>> result.txt` appends the terminal result to text file.

Answer (score 4):

I think if you reorganize the output from `tshark` using `-T fields` it's much easier. I was able to accomplish what you want like so:

```
$ tshark -r blah.pcap -T fields -e frame.len -e ip.src | sort -k 1n | tail -5
92  10.0.2.2
92  10.0.2.2
92  10.0.2.2
100 10.0.2.15
156 10.0.2.15
```

#### tshark fields

You can use this command to get a list of all the fields:

```
$ tshark -G field
```

But I found that a bit difficult to read. If you want to understand the columns in the `-G field` output, they're described here: [tshark - Dump and analyze network traffic](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/tshark.html):

```
 * Header Fields
 * -------------
 * Field 1 = 'F'
 * Field 2 = descriptive field name
 * Field 3 = field abbreviation
 * Field 4 = type (textual representation of the ftenum type)
 * Field 5 = parent protocol abbreviation
 * Field 6 = base for display (for integer types); "parent bitfield width" for FT_BOOLEAN
 * Field 7 = bitmask: format: hex: 0x....
 * Field 8 = blurb describing field
```

You can use this `grep` to filter the output if you're brave:

```
$ tshark -G fields | grep -P '\s+(ip.src|frame.len)\s+'
F   Frame length on the wire    frame.len   FT_UINT32   frame   BASE_DEC    0x0
F   Source  ip.src  FT_IPv4 ip      0x0
```

#### References

- [enter link description here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sort-command-linuxunix-examples/)
- [tshark tutorial and filter examples](https://hackertarget.com/tshark-tutorial-and-filter-examples/)
- [Counting IP occurrences in PCAP file using tshark](https://osqa-ask.wireshark.org/questions/45418/specific-ip-address-display-filter-using-tshark)
- [Specific IP address display filter using tshark](https://osqa-ask.wireshark.org/questions/45418/specific-ip-address-display-filter-using-tshark)