# How to use awk to print nth column and remove duplicates?

Tags: awk

I am using awk below to print 8th column and remove duplicates in that very column.

```
awk -F "," '{print $8}' filecsv | awk '!NF || !seen[$0]++'
```

How to do it with just one awk instead running awk twice in the above pipline

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
awk -F , '!seen[$8]++ { print $8 }' filecsv
```

This checks whether the value of the eighth field has already been seen, and only if it hasn’t, prints it.

Comment: note that `seen` is not an `awk` command but a variable name that can be *anything* (e.g. `!_[$8]++`). This lead to some confusion on the strange syntax when I first saw this really cool solution.

Comment: @RoVo indeed; it’s quite a common AWK “trick”, see [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/30178/86440) for example.