# Git log clean up from duplicate commits

Tags: linux, awk, sed, grep, logs

I am trying to clean up my git log from duplicate lines. Unfortunately, developers don't use rebase command, and due this there are many duplicate commit massages in git log.

Git log with duplicates lines

```
TASK-1: awe
TASK-1 : aaa
TASK-1: aaa bbbb   
TASK-2: aaaaa
TASK-3: 123
TASK-3 : 123 aaa
```

I need to keep first line with TASK-number and all others lines remove from git log with the same TASK-number

Expected result

```
TASK-1: awe
TASK-2: aaaaa   
TASK-3: 123
```

I try to use sort to get uniq commits

```
git log --pretty=format:"%s  " --no-merges | grep -oP --regexp="TASK-\K\d+" | sort -r | uniq
```

And this one working so I get only TASK numbers with out commit massages.

```
1
2
3
```

But when I change regex extension to `--regexp=“^[TASK-]\^*.*”` it prints all line.

Can some one help me to remove duplicates line please

Comment: Are those extra spaces before `:` typos in the input file?  Also, you can easily do it in awk. Have a look at https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/30173, you just have to adapt it to specify the field correctly instead of the whole line.

Comment: nope it is possible that developers will put space after the number in commit massage

Comment: Alright, but is `:` a reliable field separator?

Comment: Simply field coming after TASK-number