# deduplication of lines in a large file

Tags: text-processing, large-files, deduplication

The size of the file is 962,120,335 bytes.

HP-UX ******B.11.31 U ia64 ****** unlimited-user license

```
hostname> what /usr/bin/awk
/usr/bin/awk:
         main.c $Date: 2009/02/17 15:25:17 $Revision: r11.31/1 PATCH_11.31 (PHCO_36132)
         run.c $Date: 2009/02/17 15:25:20 $Revision: r11.31/1 PATCH_11.31 (PHCO_36132)
         $Revision: @(#) awk R11.31_BL2010_0503_1 PATCH_11.31 PHCO_40052
hostname> what /usr/bin/sed
/usr/bin/sed:
         sed0.c $Date: 2008/04/23 11:11:11 $Revision: r11.31/1 PATCH_11.31 (PHCO_38263)
         $Revision: @(#) sed R11.31_BL2008_1022_2 PATCH_11.31 PHCO_38263
 hostname>perl -v
    This is perl, v5.8.8 built for IA64.ARCHREV_0-thread-multi
hostname:> $ file /usr/bin/perl
/usr/bin/perl:  ELF-32 executable object file - IA64
hostname:> $ file /usr/bin/awk
/usr/bin/awk:   ELF-32 executable object file - IA64
hostname:> $ file /usr/bin/sed
/usr/bin/sed:   ELF-32 executable object file - IA64
```

There are no GNU tools here.
What are my options?

[How to remove duplicate lines in a large multi-GB textfile?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/19641/how-to-remove-duplicate-lines-in-a-large-multi-gb-textfile)

and

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_sorting#External_merge_sort

```
perl -ne 'print unless $seen{$_}++;' < file.merge > file.unique
```

throws

```
Out of Memory!
```

The resultant file of 960MB is merged from files of these sizes listed below, the average being 50 MB
22900038,
24313871,
25609082,
18059622,
23678631,
32136363,
49294631,
61348150,
85237944,
70492586,
79842339,
72655093,
73474145,
82539534,
65101428,
57240031,
79481673,
539293,
38175881

Question: How to perform external sort merge and deduplicate this data? Or, how to deduplicate this data?

Comment: The normal pattern for dedup'ing is `sort .... | uniq`. If `sort` is failing due to lack of memory then you could try breaking apart the file into many pieces (for example using `split`), depup'ing each part indidivually, `cat`ing them back together (which hopefully results in a smaller file than the original), then dedup that.

Comment: Doesn't a simple `sort -u` work? I know that the old `sort` from System V R4 used temporary files in /var/tmp if sorting in memory wasn't possible, so  large files shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Do you need to preserve the order of the first occurrences of each line? If not `sort -u` is the clear solution.

Answer (score 3):

It seems to me that the process you're following at the moment is this, which fails with your out of memory error:

1. Create several data files
2. Concatenate them together
3. Sort the result, discarding duplicate records (rows)

I think you should be able to perform the following process instead

1. Create several data files
2. Sort each one independently, discarding its duplicates (`sort -u`)
3. Merge the resulting set of sorted data files, discarding duplicates (`sort -m -u`)

Comment: How to merge? To be able to merge in reasonable time, we need some lookup logic, e.g. hash table, but then we again face the same problem -> not enough memory to store huge hash table.

Comment: @Borna why would you want a hash table when merging multiple pre-sorted files? These [external merge-sort algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_sorting) have been around since the days of magnetic tape - at least 50 years ago.

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for, thank you sir!
One question, I was wondering how efficient would it be to create n files in a single directory (under Linux), where each file name is a row from the 'non-unique-lines' file (lets say no illegal chars for the file name), and thus eliminating duplicate rows.

Comment: @Borna that sounds an interesting question in its own right. When you've asked it I'd appreciate a ping back here with the reference and I'll take a look

Answer (score 0):

Of course there are no GNU/Linux tools: *what* is part of the Source Code Control System (SCCS), which I do not believe exists at all in Linux.

So, presumably you are on Unix. There the *sort* algorithm is capable of dealing with these problems: the [Algorithmic details of UNIX Sort command](http://vkundeti.blogspot.com/2008/03/tech-algorithmic-details-of-unix-sort.html) states that an input of size *M*, with a memory of size *N*, is subdivided into *M/N* chunks that fit into memory, and which are worked upon serially.

It should fit the bill.

Comment: The question states that the op is on HP-UX. SCCS is proprietary, but you can use `what` on LInux if you install [GNU CSSC](http://www.gnu.org/software/cssc/)

Comment: [Sun open-sourced SCCS](http://heirloom.sourceforge.net/devtools.html) as part of [the Heirloom project](http://heirloom.sourceforge.net/). The [`README`](http://heirloom.cvs.sourceforge.net/heirloom/heirloom-devtools/README?view=markup) states that it has been successfully built on Linux.

Comment: @Anthon  and WarrenYoung Thanks, I did not know this.

Comment: `SCCS` is opensource on my request since December 2006. Be however careful with heirloom SCCS, since it got only attention for a few months and is dead since spring 2007. It still has bugs on Linux. The sccs project on sourceforge http://sccs.sf.net is actively maintained and without known bugs.

Answer (score 0):

```
% perl -ne 'if ( $seen{$_}++ ) {
    $count++ ;
    if ($count > 1000000) {
        $seen = () ;
        $count = 0 ;
    }
} else {
    print ;
}' <eof   
a
a
a
b
c
a
a
a
b
c
eof   
a
b
c
%
```

Comment: That only works if the file is already sorted in some order. And in that case it can be done faster with `uniq`.

Comment: Right! I fixed my slow `uniq` for a better approach based on the hypothesis the repetitions aren't too sparsed.