# Removing duplicates in a large text list

Tags: linux, shell, text-processing, files, sort

I've searched around the internet and stackexchange for this. Even though there are lots of similar topics, I haven't found a solution yet.

So, I have a quite large list (approx. 20GB), which contains around 5% duplicate lines. I want to filter this list, sothat one of the duplicates is deleted. Example:

Input:

```
test123
Test123
test
test123
test 123
```

Output:

```
test123
Test123
test
test 123
```

Whether the list gets sorted or not doesn't matter.

I've tried `sort -u -o output.txt`, also `sort -us -o output.txt`. It works fine for smaller files, but when I try to do files of more than approx. 4GB, the resulting file is suspiciously small and, instead of a .txt file, it has apparently become an "emacs-lisp-source-text".

I'd be very grateful if someone could help me out!

Comment: Possible duplicates: [How to remove duplicate lines inside a text file?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/30173/12779) and [How to remove duplicate lines in a large multi-GB textfile?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/19641/12779). Please check if the answers work for you (especially the `awk` one).

Comment: I've gone through those threads, but unfortunately the solutions don't work for me (awk seems to be even more vulnerable to errors involving large files).

Comment: You should state in your question what exactly you have tried, which commands you ran and what the console output and return value of the command was. If possible provide an example file which demonstrates the issue. But that might not be feasible if the error only shows after a certain size is reached. And clarify what you mean by “more vulnerable to errors involving large files”. Small vs. large is relative. On an old laptop with 64MiB of memory 100MiB might be large, on a server with 512GiB of memory 100GiB might be small.

Comment: And `awk '!seen[$0]++' 8GiB_file > output` works without problems here. No issues with the file size. The same goes for `sort -u -o output 8GiB_file`. Works here.

Comment: I tried that exact command earlier. Like sort -u, it doesn't work properly and creates an "emacs-lisp-source-text'. However, I think I might have found the source of the problem. All the large files I have tried contain "strange" characters (arabic, chinese, hex, ... you name it). Because this only happened with large files, I concluded that the size was likely the reason. Could it be possible, that the "sort" and "awk" command have difficulties with certain kinds of characters? And if so, do you know an alternative that doesn't?

Comment: The following works here (8+GiB of Unicode): `for i in {1..30000000}; do echo 'ᚹᛖᛥᚫ\nəsoʊsiˈeıʃn\n⠙⠳⠃⠞\ntest123\n⌷←⍳→⍴∆∇⊃‾⍎⍕⌈\nTest123\nSTARGΛ<030a>TE\ntest\nκόψη\ntest123\nსაერთაშორისო\ntest 123\nКонференцию\nพระปกเกศกองบ<0e39><0e4a>ก<0e39><0e49>ข<0e36><0e49>นใหม<0e48>\nአይታረስ\n'; done | awk '!seen[$0]++'` Furthermore, how do you find out it's a lisp source file? I don't believe that `awk`s output is lisp. Maybe some tool's heuristics fail on the content of the resulting file.

Comment: I added an answer (I've tested) below: Using `cat` to pipe the InputFile to a `while` loop, `read` each line in the loop, `grep` -F (or fgrep) the line against the desired OutputFile.  If it's not already in the OutputFile, add it to the OutputFile with `echo` (see full answer below).

Answer (score 2):

Tested with GNU `sort` from GNU coreutils 8.26, I had no problem sorting a 5GiB file. So, you could try install that one.

Things to bear in mind though:

- `sort -u` doesn't give you unique lines, but one of all the lines that sort the same. On GNU systems especially, and in your typical locale, there are several characters that sort the same. If you want unique lines at byte level, use `LC_ALL=C sort -u`.
- `sort` uses temporary files for big inputs to sort in chunks so as not to use up the whole memory. If you do not have enough space in your temporary directory (usually `/tmp` unless you have set `$TMPDIR`), then it will fail. Set `$TMPDIR` (see also the `-T` option with GNU `sort`) to a directory with enough free space.

Answer (score 0):

```
printf "">OutputFile
cat InputFile | 
while IFS= read -r line; do 
  if [ ! -z "$line" ]; then
    if ! grep -Fxqe "$line" OutputFile; then
      echo "$line">>OutputFile;
    fi
  fi
done
```

**Explanation**

Create a new OutputFile
`printf "">OutputFile`

Pipe the InputFile to a while loop
`cat InputFile |`

Read each line
`while IFS= read -r line; do`

Handle blank lines
`if [ ! -z "$line" ]; then`

Check if line is already in OutputFile
If the results are empty, it's not already in the OutputFile (i.e., it's unique)
`if ! grep -Fxqe "$line" OutputFile; then`

Put the line in OutputFile
`echo "$line">>OutputFile;`