# How to delete commands in history matching a given string?

Tags: bash, text-processing, command-history, xargs

I need to delete all commands in my history matching a string. I've tried:

```
$ history | grep searchstring | cut -d" " -f2 | history -d
-bash: history: -d: option requires an argument

$ history | grep searchstring | cut -d" " -f2 | xargs history -d
xargs: history: No such file or directory

$ temparg() { while read i; do "$@" "$i"; done }
$ history | grep searchstring | cut -d" " -f2 | temparg history -d
(no error, but nothing is deleted)
```

What is the right way to do this?

Comment: While there are working answers below, I still wonder why it doesn't work with `history -d X`. I came across this question because I had just done `history | grep search_str | sort -nr | awk '{print $1}' | while read i; do history -d $i; done`. No error, but nothing deleted. Anybody can explain why?

Comment: See this question for the why https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/599324/why-do-i-get-an-error-when-deleting-entries-from-bash-history

Answer (score 30):

The `history` command just operates on your history file, `$HISTFILE` (typically `~/.history` or `~/.bash_history`). It'll be much easier if you just remove the lines from that file, which can be done many ways. `grep` is one way, but you have to be careful not to overwrite the file while still reading it:

```
$ grep -v searchstring "$HISTFILE" > /tmp/history
$ mv /tmp/history "$HISTFILE"
```

Another way is with `sed`:

```
$ sed -i '/searchstring/d' "$HISTFILE"
```

Comment: Good answer; `$HISTFILE` could contain spaces, probably worth quoting it.

Comment: Careful... histfile is unpredictable, if you have many open shells, it's no telling what exactly will get saved and in what order. Can anyone confirm that already open shells will not rewrite the history they loaded at initialization, when closed?

Comment: _"The history command just operates on your history file,"_ -- I'm pretty sure `history` operates on the shell's runtime concept of history, which might or might not be saved to `$HISTFILE` at some point. The history mechanism works well without `$HISTFILE` at all, and AFAIK Bash doesn't even try to keep the history file consistent very aggressively. IIRC it only saves it on exit.

Answer (score 12):

Michael Mrozek's answer will work if you don't care about removing commands from the current session. If you do, you should write to the history file before doing the operations in his post by doing `history -a`.

Also, after you have removed the entries that you want from your history file, you can reload it by issuing `history -c`, then `history -r`.

Answer (score 9):

For those looking for a one-liner:

```
while history -d $(history | grep 'SEARCH_STRING_GOES_HERE'| head -n 1 | awk {'print $1'}) ; do :; history -w; done
```

So, if you wanted to eg. delete multiple lines with a password in it, simply replace "SEARCH_STRING_GOES_HERE" with the password.
This will search your entire history for that search string and delete it.

2 things to be aware of

- grep uses regex unless you supply -F as an argument
- The command will show 1 error, once there are no more matches. Ignore it.

Comment: I got an error (-bash: history: -d: option requires an argument), but it still worked?

Comment: It runs the delete command continuously, until it fails with an error (because there's is nothing more to delete). Just ignore the error.

Comment: This is not only onliner, but also the right simple answer. Yep **don't be confused about the `history: -d: option requires an argument` error! It's at the END of the while loop => expected** - it works and then basically says "I can't find anything else!" :)

Answer (score 2):

Based on [Michael](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/57925/80154) and [Chris'](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/57927/80154) answers, I came up with the following. Add it to your `~/.bashrc` file and then load it with either `. ~/.bashrc` or `source ~/.bashrc`.

```bash
:<<COMMENT
    Deletes all lines from the history that match a search string, with a
    prompt. The history file is then reloaded into memory.

    Examples
        hxf "rm -rf"
        hxf ^source

    See:
    - https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/57924/how-to-delete-commands-in-history-matching-a-given-string
COMMENT
#The unalias prevents odd errors when calling". ~/.bashrc" (May result in
#"not found" errors. That's okay).
unalias hxf
hxf() {
    read -r -p "About to delete all items from history that match \"$1\". Are you sure? [y/N] " response
    response=${response,,}    # tolower
    if [[ $response =~ ^(yes|y)$ ]]
    then
        #Delete all matched items from the file, and duplicate it to a temp
        #location.
        echo -e "grep -v \"$1\" \"$HISTFILE\" > /tmp/history"
        grep -v "$1" "$HISTFILE" > /tmp/history

        #Clear all items in the current sessions history (in memory). This
        #empties out $HISTFILE.
        echo "history -c"
        history -c

        #Overwrite the actual history file with the temp one.
        echo -e "mv /tmp/history \"$HISTFILE\""
        mv /tmp/history "$HISTFILE"

        #Now reload it.
        echo -e "history -r \"$HISTFILE\""
        history -r "$HISTFILE"     #Alternative: exec bash
    else
        echo "Cancelled."
    fi
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
cat "$HISTFILE" | grep -v "commandToDelete" >> "$HISTFILE" && exit
```

This worked for me.  history -c && history -a didn't reload the history file properly for me. So instead I just exit my session right after rewriting the history file so the one in memory doesn't overwrite it.

Comment: This command will fill up your disk with duplicated history values.

Answer (score 0):

The following commands remove any history rows with `ThisIs\*#$(#ATest123`

```
for i in $(history | grep 'ThisIs\*#$(#ATest123' | awk '{print$1}' | sort -nr); do history -d $i;done
```

- For loop through the command around `$()`
- Show history
- filter (`grep`) out only rows with `ThisIs\*#$(#ATest123`
- Use awk to only show the first column (the numbers)
- Reverse order of the numbers and sort in reverse `r`. Make sure to sort as a number `n`
- Use the list of numbers from the previous command to delete each entry `history -d $i`

If working with a variable do the following

```
remove_password='ThisIs\*#$(#ATest123'
for i in $(history | grep '"$remove_password"' | awk '{print$1}' | sort -nr); do history -d $i;done
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the idea from [How can I remove duplicates in my .bash_history, preserving order?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/179852/553195), I have following in may .bashrc,

```
cleanHistory() {
    cleanHistoryPattern="^Sp .+|^mf .+"
    history -w
    history -c
    # remove commands match pattern, still can use them in current session
    cat $HISTFILE | grep -v -P "$cleanHistoryPattern"|sponge $HISTFILE
    # remove duplications
    tac $HISTFILE | awk '!x[$0]++' | tac | sponge $HISTFILE

    history -r
}

trap cleanHistory EXIT
```