# Why do I get an error when deleting entries from Bash history?

Tags: bash, command-history, xargs

I have some commands in my Bash history that I want to remove.

I can find them with `history | grep "command with password"` then remove them with `history -d <line-number>`

However, when I try to delete them in bulk by piping them to `xargs` like this I get an error:

```
history | grep "command with password" | awk '{print $1}' | sort -r | xargs history -d
xargs: history: No such file or directory
```

I thought that `xargs` would go through the list of line numbers and send it one by one to the `history -d` command.

What is causing this error?

**NB:** I know there are other ways to delete the history, the question is purely to improve my understanding of how `xargs` works and what I am doing wrong that is causing the error.

Comment: Similar, if not duplicate: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/57924/117549

Comment: Yes, agreed. Similar in that it gives solutions to do what the OP wanted, but the question here is _why_ rather than _how_ so not a duplicate

Comment: My (untested) thought was that xargs can't call a shell built in.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The error is raised because xargs cannot find a `history` command. It is a shell builtin, as you can confirm with `type history`, thus not visible to xargs. Try

```
echo 1 | xargs history -d; echo $?
```

The return value is 127. In [`man xargs`, EXIT STATUS section](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_node/find_html/Invoking-xargs.html#Invoking-xargs):

```
0 if it succeeds
123 if any invocation of the command exited with status 1-125
124 if the command exited with status 255
125 if the command is killed by a signal
126 if the command cannot be run
127 if the command is not found
1 if some other error occurred.
```

---

Expanding on [ilkkachu's comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/599324/why-do-i-get-an-error-when-deleting-entries-from-bash-history/599329#comment1118934_599329), in principle you could invoke Bash and call `history` from the spawned shell.

```
echo 1 | xargs -I {} bash -c 'echo $HISTFILE; history' bash {}
```

The above command does not raise an error, after all the builtin `history` is available to the Bash shell. However, from that same command one also finds that `HISTFILE` is unset and `history` outputs nothing: The history is not enabled on a non-interactive shell. Again, you could activate it with the `set` builtin, export `HISTFILE` and `HISTFILESIZE`... But we don't want a headache. [Editing `.bash_history` directly](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/57924) is the straightforward way to go.

Comment: Very interesting. I never knew that xargs couldn't call shell builtins!

Comment: @opticyclic, it _could_, if it used a shell to start the programs, instead of doing it itself. And you can do it anyway with something like `xargs sh -c 'some shell code' sh`. It just wouldn't _help_ because that copy of the shell might have a different concept of the history than the main shell where you started the whole pipeline

Comment: @opticyclic It is a bit surprising at the first moment, but if you think about it, how would xargs decide on which shell to look for builtins? `bash`, `ksh`, `dash`, `zsh`? It seems reasonable that it doesn't go as far as that.

Comment: Both comments totally make sense. Very useful in helping my understanding!

Comment: @opticyclic: xargs isn't a shell-builtin itself so it runs in a separate process.  If you wanted to do something *like* it, you might write a shell loop that used `while read`, or bash array variables and iterate over them, or some other pure shell construct that can run commands inside the current shell.

Comment: @Quasímodo, it would probably use `/bin/sh`. (or on the more weird systems, some other path where it knows a POSIX shell is available; if `/bin/sh` isn't one.) Or perhaps what's in the user's `SHELL`, possibly.

Comment: _"Editing .bash_history directly is the straightforward way to go."_ -- well, except that if the command is in the history of a running shell (only), it only gets written to `$HISTFILE` when the shell exits, so it might not be there to be removed yet. Though if the shell has read some history from `$HISTFILE`, and you then remove the lines from the file, at least the shell doesn't seem to write them back. But if you have something already in `$HISTFILE`, and use `history -d` , it doesn't seem to delete it from the file. So, what you want to do depends on where the command is already stored.

Comment: For those wondering, history can work under `xargs` by forcing an interactive shell and setting the history option in bash: `echo 1 | xargs -i bash -ci 'set -o history; echo $HISTFILE; history' _ {}`. But as others pointed out, it may be preferable to edit the file itself.

Comment: @fzbd, and just to repeat the point I made above until it sticks, ___that doesn't work for removing anything from the history file___. It's not just "preferable" to edit the file itself, or to do something other than that, it's _necessary_.

Comment: @ilkkachu "preferable" depends on the user's intended task. If they just want to modify the current shell session history, my comment shows how to access it in `xargs`, which was one of the points from OP (i.e. "improve my understanding of how xargs works"). If they want to remove it persistently, they edit the file instead of using the `history` builtin. Hope that clears any confusion.

Comment: @ilkkachu Thank you for your important remarks. Particularly: "If the command is in the history of a running shell (only), it only gets written to `$HISTFILE` when the shell exits". In which case the reader should refer to [Chris Down's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/57927) in the linked question.

Comment: @ilkkachu I guess I wasn't clear, but by "current shell session" I meant the one started by xargs, of course it will be distinct from the shell session that starts xargs. My point still stands that history operations are possible to do under xargs, and it is suitable for the purpose of understanding the behaviour of interactive vs non-interactive shells regarding bash builtins.