# Avoiding similar commands in Konsole when scrolling through recent commands in Manjaro KDE

Tags: terminal, kde, command, manjaro, konsole

Imagine that I enter these commands in Konsole (Manjaro KDE terminal):

```
python3 script.py
clear
clear
```

Normally when I hit arrow UP key, I am able to scroll through recent commands: If I hit arrow UP key three times I should have these commands

```
clear
clear
python3 script.py
```

Is there a way to avoid having similar commands when hitting arrow UP key?
What I want here is to have

```
clear
python3 script.py
```

Comment: FYI, this is a function of  your shell (`bash`), not a function of the terminal (`konsole`).

Comment: If you are using `bash` (in the terminal), then yes.  Look up `history`. There is an option to remove adjacent duplicates.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I remove duplicates in my .bash\_history, preserving order?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/48713/how-can-i-remove-duplicates-in-my-bash-history-preserving-order) The first answer is to clean the existing history file, the second to configure history to ignore duplicates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following to your `~/.bashrc` if you're using `bash`:

```
export HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth:erasedups
```

If you're using `zsh`, you can try this in your `~/.zshrc`(untested):

```
setopt HIST_IGNORE_DUPS
```