# Compare 60 large files and output only the lines that are common to all files

Tags: linux, file-comparison

I Have 60 files, each contain about 10,000 lines. Each line contains a single string.

I want to find out only the strings that are common to all files.

Must be exact matches, so we are comparing the entire line.

Comment: My first thought was to read all the files, counting each string in a hash array. `awk '{ ++Cnt[$0]; }'` Use an END clause to list only those strings whose Cnt equals the number of files (which you also count). But that gives a false result if a string occurs multiple times in any file. So: are the strings unique in any one file? We can cope with this, but it would be slightly more complex.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I'd say it is unlikely that the same string would appear more than once but I can't be 100% sure. Duplicates are not required if they do exist, so we could check and clean the files beforehand. Something like sort FILE | uniq -cd

Comment: Are the files sorted?

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
awk '
    BEGINFILE{fnum++; delete f;}
    !f[$0]++{s[$0]++;}
    END {for (l in s){if (s[l] == fnum) print l}}
' files*
```

**Explanation:**

- `BEGINFILE { ... }` Run at beginning of each file

  - `fnum++` increment file counter
  - `delete f` [delete array](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/147957/delete-an-array-in-awk) which is used used to [filter duplicate lines per file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/11941/236063) (see link for posix-compliant solution).
- `!f[$0]++ { ... }` Run only for first occurence of a line in a file (when `f[$0]` is 0 (false))

  - `s[$0]++` Increment line-counter.
- `END { ... }` Run once at the end

  - `for (l in s){if (s[l] == fnum) print l}` Loop lines and print each one where number of occurences equals the number of files.

600.000 lines should be fine in memory. Otherwise, you could possibly remove everything from `s` which is less than `fnum` in the `BEGINFILE{...}` block.

Comment: (note that it assumes files are not empty as FNR==1 would not trigger on empty files).

Comment: Ok thank you. Sorry for being slow, but I'm assuming I place all the files within a directory and run this?

Comment: Whatever is easier for you. You can also refer the files individually like `awk '...' /path/to/file1 /path/to/file2 /path/to/fileN`, at the end, the files need to be the arguments to that `awk` command.

Comment: Sorry :( can you confirm that files* at the end of the command in your example refers to all files in the current directory?

Comment: won't modern awk have a `BEGINFILE` pattern trigerred at each new file ?

Comment: @Chris all files (excluding hidden) in current directory are just `*`

Comment: I never used `BEGINFILE`, but seems to be better option `FNR==1`, edited.

Comment: Ok so does the command count all the files in current directory? Or do I need to specify the files? Can you update your answer to a working example please? Or how do I make it run on all files in a directory? I'm sorry I'm not an advanced user.

Comment: `files*` will include all files which name are starting with "files". If you want **all** files in the directory, use `*`. This is very basic shell knowledge, maybe you should look up, it's called "globbing". Without knowing your directory / files structure I cannot give a "working example".

Comment: I understand wildcards and globbing but I don't know scripting  - so as far as I knew "files" might be part of the command. You included the word "files*" - how am I to determine that this is, or is not part of the command without clarification?
So.. just to be perfectly clear, I can simply paste the following into the command line form the directory containing the files?

awk '
    BEGINFILE{fnum++; delete f;}
    !f[$0]++{s[$0]++;}
    END {for (l in s){if (s[l] == fnum) print l}}
' *

Comment: exactly .......

Comment: Great stuff - thanks :-) I will test!

Answer (score 1):

Parallelized version in bash. It should work for files bigger than memory.

```bsh
export LC_ALL=C
comm -12 \
  <(comm -12 \
    <(comm -12 \
      <(comm -12 \
        <(comm -12  <(comm -12  <(sort 1) <(sort 2);) <(comm -12  <(sort 3) <(sort 4););) \
        <(comm -12  <(comm -12  <(sort 5) <(sort 6);) <(comm -12  <(sort 7) <(sort 8);););) \
      <(comm -12 \
        <(comm -12  <(comm -12  <(sort 9) <(sort 10);) <(comm -12  <(sort 11) <(sort 12););) \
        <(comm -12  <(comm -12  <(sort 13) <(sort 14);) <(comm -12  <(sort 15) <(sort 16););););) \
    <(comm -12 \
      <(comm -12 \
        <(comm -12  <(comm -12  <(sort 17) <(sort 18);) <(comm -12  <(sort 19) <(sort 20););) \
        <(comm -12  <(comm -12  <(sort 21) <(sort 22);) <(comm -12  <(sort 23) <(sort 24);););) \
      <(comm -12 \
        <(comm -12  <(comm -12  <(sort 25) <(sort 26);) <(comm -12  <(sort 27) <(sort 28););) \
        <(comm -12  <(comm -12  <(sort 29) <(sort 30);) <(comm -12  <(sort 31) <(sort 32);););););) \
  <(comm -12 \
    <(comm -12 \
      <(comm -12 \
        <(comm -12  <(comm -12  <(sort 33) <(sort 34);) <(comm -12  <(sort 35) <(sort 36););) \
        <(comm -12  <(comm -12  <(sort 37) <(sort 38);) <(comm -12  <(sort 39) <(sort 40);););) \
      <(comm -12 \
        <(comm -12  <(comm -12  <(sort 41) <(sort 42);) <(comm -12  <(sort 43) <(sort 44););) \
        <(comm -12  <(comm -12  <(sort 45) <(sort 46);) <(comm -12  <(sort 47) <(sort 48););););) \
    <(comm -12 \
      <(comm -12 \
        <(comm -12  <(comm -12  <(sort 49) <(sort 50);) <(comm -12  <(sort 51) <(sort 52););) \
        <(comm -12  <(comm -12  <(sort 53) <(sort 54);) <(comm -12  <(sort 55) <(sort 56);););) \
      <(cat  <(comm -12  <(comm -12  <(sort 57) <(sort 58);) <(comm -12  <(sort 59) <(sort 60););) ;);););
```

Replace `sort` with `cat` if the files are already sorted.

Comment: Would make more sense to use `comm -12` instead of `join` here. You'd probably want `export LC_ALL=C`, and use `sort -u`. Note that the `;`s are not necessary.

Comment: If the files are already sorted, you'd rather replace `<(sort file)` with `file` than with `<(cat file)`.

Answer (score 0):

With `zsh`, using its `${a:*b}` array intersection operator on arrays marked with the *unique* flag (also using the `$(<file)` ksh operator and `f` parameter expansion flag to split on line feed characters):

```
#! /bin/zsh -
typeset -U all list
all=(${(f)"$(<${1?})"}); shift
for file do
  list=(${(f)"$(<$file)"})
  all=(${all:*list})
done
print -rC1 -- $all
```

(that script takes the list of files as arguments; empty lines are ignored).

Answer (score 0):

With `join`:

```
cp a jnd
for f in a b c; do join jnd $f >j__; cp j__ jnd; done
```

I have just numbers (1-6, 3-8, 5-9) in three files a, b and c. This is the two lines (numbers, strings) the three have in common.

```
]# cat jnd
5
6
```

---

It is not elegant/efficient like that, especially with that `cp` in between. But it can be made to work in parallel quite easily. Select a subgroup of files (`for f in a*`), give the files unique names and then you can run many subgroups at once. You still have to join these results... - with 64 files you would have 8 threads joining 8 files each, and then the remaining 8 joined files could again be split up, into 4 threads.